# Null check operator used on a null value in flutter StreamBuilder

Tags: flutter

```
Widget build(context) {
    return Scaffold(
      appBar: header(context, isApp: true, titleText: 'Instagram'),
      body: StreamBuilder<QuerySnapshot>(
        stream: userRef.snapshots(),
        builder: (context, snapshot) {
          if (!snapshot.hasData) {
            circularProgress();
          }

          final List<Text> list = snapshot.data!.docs
              .map((user) => Text(user['username']))
              .toList();

          return Container(
            child: ListView(
              children: list,
            ),
          );
        },
      ),
    );
  }
```

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The error message appears to be referring to the null check operator in this line

```
    final List<Text> list = snapshot.data!.docs
          .map((user) => Text(user['username']))
          .toList();
```

implying that snapshot.data is null at this point.

Clearly you don't intend for this code to be executed if no data has been returned.

Since this block of code

```
if (!snapshot.hasData) {
    circularProgress();
}
```

has no return statement, execution continues down the block.

Changing it to

```
if (!snapshot.hasData) {
    return circularProgress();
}
```

should solve your problem